# Add percentage axis to Seaborn catplot with correct axis tick labels

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm plotting the counts of a categorical variable and want to add a second y-axis that shows the percentage of the total number of samples.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

titanic = sns.load_dataset("titanic")

g = sns.catplot(x="alive", col="embark_town", col_wrap=4,
                data=titanic[titanic.deck.notnull()],
                kind="count", height=4, aspect=.8)

for i, ax in enumerate(g.axes.flat):
    
    # Create second y-axis for the percentages on the right
    ax1 = ax.twinx()
    
    ### Attempt to fix percentages by plotting the bars over
    #g = sns.catplot(x="alive", col="embark_town", col_wrap=4,
    #            data=titanic[titanic.deck.notnull()],
    #            kind="count", height=4, aspect=.8,
    #            ax = ax1)
    
    # Label by the percentages
    ax1.set_ylim(ax.get_ylim())
    ax1.set_yticklabels(np.round(ax.get_yticks()/titanic[titanic.deck.notnull()].shape[0],1))
    ax1.set_ylabel('Percentage')

    # Rotate x-labels
    labels = ax.get_xticklabels() # get x labels
    ax.set_xticklabels(labels, rotation=90)
  
# Ensure good spacing  
g.fig.tight_layout()
```

Right, now my issue is that the percentages are being duplicated on the right y-axis, as show in the image below

[image]

I've tried to correct this by plotting the counts on the new axis, but that adds another row of subplots (see commented out code in the for loop). How can I get the right y-axis labels to not have duplicate values and actually reflect the percentages of the total count?

Comment: Your labels appear "duplicated" because you round the ratios to just one decimal (just change `1` to `3` to see the difference). 

Maybe multiplicate them by `100`, e.g. something like this: `percent = (ax.get_yticks() / titanic[titanic.deck.notnull()].shape[0] * 100).astype('int')` and `ax1.set_yticklabels(percent)`
`

Comment: Hahaha good catch!

Answer (score 1):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

titanic = sns.load_dataset("titanic")

g = sns.catplot(x="alive", col="embark_town", col_wrap=4,
                data=titanic[titanic.deck.notnull()],
                kind="count", height=4, aspect=.8)

# calculate numbre of samples:
total_samples = len(titanic[titanic.deck.notnull()])


for i, ax in enumerate(g.axes.flat):
    
#     bounds of the left y-axis:
    ymin, ymax = ax.get_ylim()    
    
#     # Create second y-axis for the percentages on the right    
    ax1 = ax.twinx()
    
    # scale right axis labels to total samples and mutliply with 100 for percentages
    ax1.set_ylim(100*ymin/total_samples, 100*ymax/total_samples)
    
# Ensure good spacing  
g.fig.tight_layout()
```